# Python 3.4 - Capture block of text based on single string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have searched far and wide and I hope someone can either point me to the link I missed or help me out with this logic.

We have a script the goes out and collects logs from various devices and places them in text files.  Within these text files there is a time stamp and we need to collect the few lines of text before and after this time stamp.

I already have a script that matches the time stamps and removes them for certain reports (included below) but I cannot figure out how to match the time stamp and then capture the surrounding lines.

```
regex_time_stamp = re.compile('\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}|\d{1,2}y\d{1,2}w\d{1,2}d|\d{1,2}w\d{1,2}d|\d{1,2}d\d{1,2}h')
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            h = f.readlines()
            for line in h:
                if regex_time_stamp.search(line) is not None:
                    new_line = re.sub(regex_time_stamp, '', line)
                    pre_list.append(new_line)
                else:
                    pre_list.append(line)
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: ` collect the few lines of text before and after this time stamp` what's `few ` here

Comment: Have you tried `for num,line in enumerate(h):` and then `h[num-2:num+3]`?.

Comment: I apologize for not being more specific.  It is a block of 3 lines before and two lines after.  @TigerhawkT3 I will give your suggestion a shot right now!

Answer (score 0):

The basic algorithm is to remember the three most recently read lines. When you match a header, read the next two lines and the combine it with the header and the last three lines that you've saved.

Alternately, since you're saving all of the lines in a list, simply keep track of which element is the current element, and when you find a header you can go back and get the previous two and next two elements.

Answer (score 0):

**Catch with duplicated lines**

Agreed with the basic algorithm by @Bryan-Oakley and @TigerhawkT3, however there's a catch:

*What if several lines match consecutively?*

You could end up duplicating "context" lines by printing the last 2 lines of the first match, and then the last 2 lines of the second match... that would actually also contain the previous matched line.

The solution is to keep track of which line number was last printed, in order to print just enough lines *before* the current matched line.

**Flexible context parameter**

What if also you want to print 3 lines before and after instead of 2? Then you need to keep track of more lines.

What if you want only 1 ?

Then your number of lines to print needs to be a parameter and the algorithm needs to use it.

**Sample input and output**

Here's a file sample that contains the word *MATCH* instead of your timestamp, for clarity. The other lines contain *NOT + line number*
`==
NOT 0
NOT 1
NOT 2
NOT 3
NOT 4
MATCH LINE 5
NOT 6
NOT 7
NOT 8
NOT 9
MATCH LINE 10
MATCH LINE 11
NOT 12
MATCH LINE 13
NOT 14
==`

The output should be: 
`==
NOT 3
NOT 4
 LINE 5
NOT 6
NOT 8
NOT 9
 LINE 10
 LINE 11
NOT 12
 LINE 13
NOT 14
==`

**Solution**

This solution iterates on the file and keeps track of:

- what is the last line that was printed? This will take care of not duplicating "context" lines if matched lines come in sequence.
- what is the last line that was matched? This will tell the program to print the current line if it is "close" to the last matched line. How close? This is determined by your "number of lines to print" parameter. Then we also set the last_line_printed variable to the current line index.

Here's a simplified algorithm in English:

- When matching a line we will:

  - print the last N lines, from the last_line_printed variable to the current index
  - print the current line after stripping the timestamp
  - set the last_line_printed = last_line_matched = current line index
  - continue
- When not matching a line we will:

  - print the current line if current_index < last_line_matched index + number_of_lines_to_print
- Of course we're taking care of whether we're close to the beginning of file by checking limits

**Not print but return an array**

This solution doesn't print directly but returns an array with all the lines to print. That's just a bit classier.

I like to name my "return" variable `result` but that's just me. It makes it obvious what is the result variable during the whole algorithm.

**Code**

You can try this code with the input above, it'll print the same output.

```
def search_timestamps_context(filename, number_of_lines_to_print=2):
    import re
    result = []
    regex_time_stamp = re.compile('\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}|\d{1,2}y\d{1,2}w\d{1,2}d|\d{1,2}w\d{1,2}d|\d{1,2}d\d{1,2}h')
    # for my test
    regex_time_stamp = re.compile('MATCH')
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
                h = f.readlines()
                # Remember which is the last line printed and matched
                last_line_printed = -1
                last_line_matched = -1
                for idx, line in enumerate(h):
                    if regex_time_stamp.search(line) is not None:
                        # We want to print the last "number_of_lines_to_print" lines
                        # ...unless they were already printed
                        # We want to return last lines from idx - number_of_lines_to_print 
                        # print ('** Matched ', line, idx, last_line_matched, last_line_printed)
                        if last_line_printed == -1:
                            lines_to_print = max(idx - number_of_lines_to_print, 0)
                        else: 
                            # Unless we've already printed those lines because of a previous match, then we continue
                            lines_to_print = max(idx - number_of_lines_to_print, last_line_printed + 1)
                        for l in h[lines_to_print:idx]:
                            result.append(l)
                        # Now print the stripped line
                        new_line = re.sub(regex_time_stamp, '', line)
                        result.append(new_line)
                        # Update the last line printed 
                        last_line_printed = last_line_matched = idx

                    else:
                        # If not a match, we still need to print the current line if we had a match N lines before
                        if last_line_matched != -1 and idx < last_line_matched + number_of_lines_to_print:
                            result.append(line)
                            last_line_printed = idx
    return result

filename = 'test_match.txt'
lines = search_timestamps_context(filename, number_of_lines_to_print=2)
print (''.join(lines))
```

**Improvements**

The usage of `getlines()` is inefficient: we are reading the whole file before starting.

It would be more efficient to just iterate, but then we need to remember the last lines in case we need to print them. To achieve that, we would maintain a list of the last N lines, and not more.

That's an exercise left to the reader :)